# Meteor Service temporarily unavailable on delete and re-upload

Tags: meteor

`Error deploying application: Service temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.`

This is what I get trying to deploy to an address which I had just previously deleted with `meteor deploy <name> --delete`

I've tried about 20 times with no luck, yesterday night and this morning. Other domains work just fine.  My facebook oath details are set to the old domain.  How do I get this working?

Comment: Seems like a bug - I'm experiencing this as well.

Comment: I'm also seeing this bug.  I've contacted Meteor support about this and will post here if I receive a helpful reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Meteor, and I have confirmed this behavior - thanks for the report @Austin. MDG engineering is looking at this - I'll update this when we know more.

---

UPDATE: The problem has been resolved for all future `--delete`s. Due to the nature of the problem (`--delete`s were failing to remove everything that needed to be deleted) sites that had problems before may still fail as before. We will correct that in the coming days. I'll keep an eye on this thread during that time in case anyone is really stuck.

Comment: I updated the response above (not sure if SO notifies on edits, so adding a comment as well)